# React setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a function that will increase a time variable every second. So I do this:

```
 const [time, setTime]=useState(0)
function startRecord(){
start()
setClicked(true)
setInterval(()=>{
    setTime(prev=>prev+1)

},1000)
}

function stopRecord(){
setTime(0)
 stop()
 setClicked(false)
}
```

But the problem I'm encountering is that whenever I reset the time `setTime(0)`, and then I restart setting the time, the `time` that is being displayed increments every milisecond for some reason.
Here is a video:
https://gyazo.com/4335c5c05a86c4f1d62271a8bc4e4fdd
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the interval ID in state (or in a ref), and when you do `setClicked(false)`, also clear the interval:

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(0)
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();
function startRecord() {
    start()
    setClicked(true)
    setIntervalId(setInterval(() => {
        setTime(prev => prev + 1)
    }, 1000));
}

function stopRecord() {
    setTime(0)
    stop()
    setClicked(false)
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```